# Access form element attributes in Django template

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I access an input element attribute, say `aria-describedby`, in Django template syntax?

As shown below, in the template I can access the label as `{{form.email.label}}`, but how do I get the attribute `aria-describedby`?

```html
<!-- Django 2.2.9 -->
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}">{{form.email.label}}</label>
    {{ form.email }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The file `form.py` is listed below.

```py
# Django 2.2.9
from django import forms

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(
          label="Email address",
          widget=forms.EmailInput(
              attrs = {
                  "class":"form-control",
                  "placeholder":"Enter email",
                  "aria-describedby":"EmailHelp"
              }
           )
      )
```

Using `{{ form.email }}` in the template, the code listed in `forms.py` will render an input element as shown below.

```html
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Enter email" aria-describedby="EmailHelp" required id="id_email">
```

It would be convenient if it was possible to access the `aria-describedby` attribute using use some code like  `{{form.email.aria_describedby}}`.

## Notes

1. There are other similar question on SO suggesting to use syntax like `{{form.email.widget.attrs.placeholder}}`, *however, in Django 2.2.9 this does not work*. Comment: No, this syntax works in Django 2.2.9. The problem is the use of special characters, like hyphens.
2. I would prefer not to use any addional packages, like Crispy forms.

## Additional code lisings

views.py

```py
# Djano 2.2.9
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from . forms import ExampleForm

def contact(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        return redirect('example-index')

    form = ExampleForm()
    context = {'form':form}

    return render(request,'example/index.html',context)
```

index.html

```html
<!-- Django 2.2.9 -->
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}">{{form.email.label}}</label>
    {{ form.email }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

<h2>Accessing form field attributes in the Django template</h2>

<p><code>form.email.label</code>
         =  {{form.email.label}} </p>

<p><code>form.email.id_for_label</code>
         =  {{form.email.id_for_label}} </p>

<p><code>form.email.aria_describedby</code>
         = {{form.email.aria_describedby}} </p>

<p><code>form.email.widget.attrs.class</code>
         = {{form.email.widget.attrs.class}} </p>
```

urls.py

```py
# Django 2.2.9
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns= [
    path('',views.contact, name="example-index"),
]
```

Answer (score 3):

After additional investigations of the problem presented in the question, I found a solution and decided to write it up here.

Accessing *input form attributes* using Django template syntax are in all cases straightforward, except when the key contains a special character, e.g. a hyphen `-`. For example, all attributes, as specified in the file `forms.py` listed in the question, can be accessed in the Django template like shown below

```html
<!-- Django 2.2.9 template file -->
<p>0. {{form.email}}</p>
<p>1. {{form.email.field.label}}</p>
<p>2. {{form.email.field.max_length}}</p>
<p>3. {{form.email.field.widget.attrs.class}}</p>
<p>4. {{form.email.field.widget.attrs.placeholder}}</p>
```

The image below shows the rendering in the web browser

[image: Screen capture of the web browser]

Accessing the attribute `aria-describedby` is however more complex as a hyphen, a special symbol, is used. A solution is to write a custom template filter, for example called `get_key_value`, and in the template call the filter using the pipe symbol, i.e.  `{{form.email.field.widget.attrs|get_key_value:"aria-describedby"}}`

## Custom template filter

Here is my outline of writing a custom template filter, mostly based on the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/):

**a.** Add a folder to to the app directory called `templatetags` and in this folder add two files, an empty file called `__init__.py` and a file called `myapp_extras.py`.

**b.** Add the following code to `myapp_extras.py`.

```py
# Django 2.2.9
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name="get_key_value")
def get_key_value(some_dict,key):
    return some_dict.get(key,'')
```

**c.** In `settings.py` add the filter to the list of installed apps.  Note, I called my app `myapp`, also added to the list.

```py
# Django 2.2.9
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    'myapp.templatetags.myapp_extras'
]
```

**D.** Load the custom filters in the template, and apply the filter `get_key_value`

```html
<!-- Django 2.2.9 template file -->
{% load myapp_extras %}

<p>0. {{form.email}}</p>
<p>1. {{form.email.field.label}}</p>
<p>2. {{form.email.field.max_length}}</p>
<p>3. {{form.email.field.widget.attrs.class}}</p>
<p>4. {{form.email.field.widget.attrs.placeholder}}</p>

<p>5. {{form.email.field.widget.attrs|get_key_value:"aria-describedby"}}</p>
```

In the browser this renders like shown below, note point 5 where the value for the key `aria-describedby` is shown as `EmailHelp`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One can get the placeholder easily by this

```
form.email.widget.attrs.placeholder
```

If you're doing this in a loop like this

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.field.widget.attrs.placeholder }} # field.field is the key here
{% endfor %}
```